# Check internet connection when user interacts

Tags: ios

Where I should implement a function to check internet connection on user's iPhone every time?
Exactly:

- when some `ViewController` appears
- when user goes to home screen and returns to app via multitasking

I have a lot of `.swift` files and I don't want to implement code in every `viewWillApear` function of every `.swift` file. Maybe there is some native place somewhere in AppDelegate or else?

Comment: Typically you check when the user taps a button or whatever that initiates an action that requires a network call.

Comment: From ["Connect without preflight"](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010220-CH213-SW25): *"The Reachability APIs ... are intended for diagnostic purposes after identifying a connectivity issue. Many apps incorrectly use these APIs to proactively check for an Internet connection ..."*

Comment: You just try connect and it either works or it doesn't. You have not shown your connection code, but URLSession behaves gracefully so just use it and be happy. There is a WWDC 2017 video that goes into this very topic in some depth.

Comment: @matt Thanks, Matt! I want to receive this as answer, please post it like an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Where I should implement a function to check internet connection on user's iPhone every time?

You shouldn't. The way to ask if the network is working is simply to try to use the network. You just attempt to do your networking and either you succeed or you fail in good order, and you take it from there. Most networking is done with URLSession, which will handle this gracefully for you, and in iOS 11 can even be configured to try again later automatically (`waitsForConnectivity`). Please watch the [relevant WWDC 2017 video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/709/) for further discussion.